# How can I change file code colour in GitHub

Tags: python, github

I am new to GitHub, and I noticed that when I created a new file, the code was completely grey, as shown in Fig.1: [image]

But I also noticed that other users have 'coloured' files as shown in Fig.2:
[image]

Is it possible to make Fig.1 code coloured as well?

Comment: What is the filename for the file in fig-1 and what is the programming language?

Comment: @Y4glory The language is Python. The file is a part of a repository I created, there wasn't a particular format, if that's what you are asking..

Comment: Fig 2 seems to be an exe file or a bash script. Github tries to detect the file type and does the syntax highlighting. In order to detect the filetype properly, it would check the name of the file with the extension. for eg `<filename>.py` would result in python syntax highlighting and `<filename>.js` would result in javascript syntax highlighting. That's why I wanted to know your file name.

Comment: @Y4glory I see what you mean.. There is no suffix, just whatever I named it, eg. fill_between

Comment: So if it has no file extension github will be unable to highlight syntax unless its something like a gitignore or a dockerFile or some other special filetype like that

Comment: @Y4glory So I didn't tick the gitignore box and that's why.  Would I be able to include the gitignore after the repository had been created?

Comment: No it's not an issue with gitignore box. What I mean is your file does not have an extension (as you said) so GitHub won't be able to detect the filetype.

Comment: @Y4glory I added `.py` and it worked! Thank you:)

Comment: *Fig 1* is clearly not python, and probably not a supported syntax, that's why it's not highlighted by default.

Comment: @krisz Yeah it was meant to be an example, but thank you for pointing out!